# Base Directory Change Issue

Tags: php

In my app, I'm using an AJAX call to retrieve information, which requires the inclusion of a db_connect.php file. db_connect.php requires other files for it to work.

If I include db_connect.php from the AJAX file, naturally, errors are returned from includes within the db_connect.php file because db_connect.php's includes are relative to the base directory of my application.

How can I change the working directory to the base directory of the application, so the included files will function properly?

What I've tried is using the `chdir` function:

```
echo getcwd() . "<br/>";
chdir("../../");
echo getcwd();
```

This correctly outputs:

```
/my/webserver/app/lib/ajax  
/my/webserver/app
```

However, the include errors act like I haven't just changed the directory:

> Warning: include_once(functions/clean_string.func.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in my/webserver/app/lib/ajax/ajax.php on line 8

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't show us your directory structure, the path you're requesting or the include statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use absolute paths.

For example in a config file, that resides in base of the app, define a base path that is absolute.

```
define("BASE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__)); //This now is a ABSOLUTE path to a dir that this file is in.
```

Then use:

```
include BASE_PATH . "/dir/dir/file.php";
```

Then, you just have to include the config file in every script at then top relatively from where you are in the app and then just use BASE_PATH in all other includes.

Answer (score -1):

`getcwd()` does not return your include path; instead, try something like this:

```
chdir("../../");
include(getcwd()."/functions/clean_string.func.php");
```